# Every node in binary tree = sum of subtree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I wrote this in Java (I know that the brackets don't exactly follow the standard way of doing it in Java - so it looks a bit like C#). But I was wondering how this algorithm is percieved. I have seen some iterative ways of solving the problem - but I thought recursion improves readability here.

Every node in a Binary Tree, has to have the value of it's subtree.

```
   8
  /  \
 3    2
/ \
1  2
```

Would be an example of such a tree. (1+2 = 3 at the bottom, and 1 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 8 at the top). An empty tree is considered 'valid'.

```
public boolean isValid()
{
    return isValid(root);
}

public boolean isValid(BinaryNode<E> node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return true;

    int sum = sumOfSub(node.getLeft()) + sumOfSub(node.getRight());

    if (node.getLeft() != null && node.getRight() != null)
    {
        if ((Integer) node.getData() != sum)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return true;

    return isValid(node.getLeft()) && isValid(node.getRight());
}

private int sumOfSub(BinaryNode node)
{
    if (node == null) return 0;
    int value = (Integer) node.getData();
    return value + sumOfSub(node.getLeft()) + sumOfSub(node.getRight());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code could probably be simplified

> ```
> if (node.getLeft() != null && node.getRight() != null)
> {
>     if ((Integer) node.getData() != sum)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> else
>     return true;
> ```

First off, don't do an else statement without curly braces when the corresponding if statement has curly braces, it doesn't follow expected coding practices.

Then you should return early

```
if (node.getLeft() == null || node.getRight() == null) {
    return true;
} else if ((Integer) node.getData() != sum) {
    return false;
}
```

---

As your code is written in the original post it will never hit this statement

> ```
> return isValid(node.getLeft()) && isValid(node.getRight());
> ```

and will always `return true`, if `(node.getLeft() == null || node.getRight() == null)`

Comment: The last return-statement will actually be hit, if the sum matches; however, this return-statement should logically be placed in a else-case of the nested if-statement, or directly after this if-statement. This would enhance readability and reduce confusion.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I updated my answer, hopefully to make it clearer what I was saying. I don't follow what you are saying if the sum matches....matches what?

Comment: In the nested if: if `(Integer) node.getData() != sum` yields `false`, i.e. the sum equals the nodes value, then the `return false;` statement is not executed, the else-case of the surrounding if is skipped and the last return-statement is executed. The last statement can be hit!

Comment: I never said it wouldn't be hit, please read carefully, I said if the first condition is false it will always run the code in else statement

Comment: OK, I overlooked the continuation of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compute the sum every time: this is terrible for performance, as you are re-evaluating the same nodes again and again (think of a leaf, it gets evaluated for every node in the chain!).

A tree that has the property you described follows the following rule:

for each node:

- if I'm a leaf, I can hold any value
- otherwise, my value must be f(right) + f(left)

where f(node) is defined as:

- If n is a leaf, f(n) = value(n)
- if n is not a leaf, f(n) = 2*value(n)

This is because leaves only carry their own weight, while nodes bring both their value and the value of their subtrees (hence 2x)

There may be some edge cases that I missed, but the gist of the solution would become something like:

```
boolean isValidNode(node) {
  if (!isLeaf(node)) return node.value == f(node.left) + f(node.right);
  else return true;
}

int f(node) {
   if (node==null) return 0;
   else if (isLeaf(node)) return node.value;
   else return 2*node.value;
}

boolean isValidNodeRec(node) {
  if (node==null) return true;
  else return isValidNode(node) && isValidNodeRec(node.left) && isValidNodeRec(node.right);
}

boolean isValidTree(root) {
  isValidNodeRec(root);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is difficult to read. The jump from the nested if-statement to the final return-statement, if the node value is equal to the calculated sum, is not obvious. Proceed step by step in a logical way, by successively handling and eliminating cases.

Let's add this method to the `BinaryNode<E>` class

```
public boolean isLeafNode()
{
    return left == null && right == null;
}
```

I suggest to change the `isValid` method like this:

```
public boolean isValid(BinaryNode<E> node)
{
    if (node == null || node.isLeafNode())
        return true;

    if (!isValid(node.getLeft()) || !isValid(node.getRight()))
        return false;

    int sum = sumOfSub(node.getLeft()) + sumOfSub(node.getRight());
    return (Integer)node.getData() == sum;
}
```

Note that the rule should be:

> Every node's value must be the sum of the values of the nodes of its
>   subtree, unless the node is a leaf node (in which case its subtree is
>   an empty tree). A leaf node is always valid.

Without the last statement a leaf node's value would always have to be `0`.

No if-statement is required for the test of the sum; just return the result of the comparison. This version can be read in a very linear way, without confusing jumps and else cases.